# jQuery dynamically set top property to display huge child category list within current page frame

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, opencart

I'm having a left category menu in my opencart site.

Some piece of code is

```
<div id="menu_box">
    <div class="box-heading">Categories</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="http://localhost/makeatech/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=224">Game Cd's</a> 
                <ul class="second-level" style="position: absolute; left: 166px; top: -2px; padding: 5px; margin: 0px; width: 350px; background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); border: 1px solid rgb(236, 236, 236); z-index: 10; display: block;">
                    <li id="third-li">
                        <a href="http://localhost/makeatech/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=224_226"> SONY Playstations</a>                            
                    </li>
                    <li id="third-li">
                        <a href="http://localhost/makeatech/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=224_225"> Xbox</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>.......</li>                     
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I'm having a huge list of categories with 3 levels of subcategories. So below categories are going down to screen.

I know the problem is with `fixed top css`. Is there any way to display all my categories within screen using jquery like [flipkart.com](http://www.flipkart.com)

Please give me your suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a menu like flipkart.com you should have a `relative` -> `absolute` relation between parent and children. To give you an example:

- make the main menu (parent) have a `position: relative;` (the `UL`
  element after `<div class="box-heading">`)
- make the sub-menu elements (children) have `position: absolute;` (you already have this on `<ul class="second-level">`)
- also you should take the children out of the screen (either by using `left: -999em;` or by using `display: none;`)

A basic CSS style could look like:

```
.box-heading > ul {
  position: relative;
}

.box-heading .second-level {
  position: absolute; 
  left: -999em; 
  top: -2px; 
  padding: 5px; 
  margin: 0px; 
  width: 350px; 
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); 
  border: 1px solid rgb(236, 236, 236); 
  z-index: 10; 
  display: block;
}

.box-heading li:hover .second-level {
  left: 166px;
}
```